# JSXGraph stop board panning after down event

Tags: javascript, jsxgraph

I am trying to disable the panning of the JSXGraph board and I found that the following does the trick.

board.attr.pan.enabled = false;

The issue is that if I set the enabled to false after the touch down event(Basically the board will be in pan mode at this point) then the panning will only be disabled after touch up event and not immidiatley. Is there any way to disable pan right away even in mid pan gesture.

Answer (score 1):

Finally found a way to force this behavior. I am going to write the answer just in case if someone else has this problem.

So just to explain what I was trying to achieve. I wanted to find a way to stop the graph panning which was easy enough and can be done with the following line.

```
board.attr.pan.enabled = false;
```

The issue that I encountered was that the panning will not be disabled if we are already in the pan mode. I was finally able to stop the panning no matter in which mode I am by doing the following.

```
board.attr.pan.enabled = false;
board.mode = JXG.Board.BOARD_MODE_NONE;
```

Comment: Interesting! May I ask you in which situation you need to interrupt the panning?

Comment: I was implementing a glider where I wanted for the glider to be created and start moving it on touchmove event. The problem was that the panning was starting to happen at this situation and now I disable panning on down event and re-enable it on up event.

Comment: Another possibility would be to demand that panning needs two fingers glider moevement is done by one finger:  `pan: {
                needShift: true,
                needTwoFingers: true,
                enabled: true
            }`

Comment: We use two finger gestures for zooming in and out. Will two finger panning still work with this approach?

Comment: It works, but it may be difficult for the users to achieve the desired result.